# Laravel accesing data from db inside controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get data from one form and save it to another db table with modifications. But, I am getting error:

> trying to get property of non-object

on the last line from the given block of codes.

```
$ply->team_name = $request->get('team_name');

    $team_name=$ply->team_name;
    $team=Team::find($team_name);
    $team->balance=$team->balance-$ply->sold_amount;
```

Comment: Most probably $team is null because it was not found in the previous line.

Comment: the problem is here `$team=Team::find($team_name);` find is equivalent to where id = $var so it will return null to fix it try this `$team=Team::where('name', $team_name)->get();`

Answer (score 1):

The find method expects an id as parameter, when you are giving it a string.

```
Model::find($id);
```

You can use the where clause :

```
Model::where('name', $name)->first();
/*
 * Or
*/
Model::where('name', $name)->get();
```

Aftet that, you should check if your $team is not null before trying to access its properties.

Finally, I strongly recommend to use the `dd($var)` for debugging purpose, it is very helpful.

Comment: there is no problem here `$team->balance=$team->balance-$ply->sold_amount;` this is equivalent to `$team->balance -= $ply->sold_amount;` ;)

Comment: It is okay. I also forgot to change the primary key.

Comment: Still getting property balance not found. With dd($team) getting 0 inside array as output.

Comment: `Collection {#188 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Team {#187 ▶}
  ]
}`

Comment: You have your team inside the array, check its property names.
Dumb question : The balance field exists on the database right ?

Comment: The problem was, I had same column name in both of the db tables. Thank you, everyone.